# Rails 4 - Simple Form - Jquery - How to add a class to an option in a selectbox

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am so confused - your help would be much appreciated. Could one kindly tell me how to add a class to a specific option in a select box.

As per the image, i would like to add a class only to the option: `<option value="4">both X men & X women</option>` but i am unsure how

_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for [@user, @social] do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.association :category_quantitygender, collection: CategoryQuantitygender.all, prompt: "select a category", label: "Quantity Gender Selection", input_html: { class: 'category_select' } %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

i tried the below but no luck:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#social_category_quantitygender_id').addClass($('here').val() == 4));
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ......

```
$('#social_category_quantitygender_id').find("option[value='4']").addClass("here")
```

Hope this will work for you.............

Comment: Thanks @akshay ! your answer is the best as it allows me to place a class on a specific option value. Thank you soo much!!!

Comment: @ARTLoe : Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the link for the add class in the select box [link](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#user-content-wrapping-rails-form-helpers)